# Fetching more data from binance using python loop

Tags: python, binance

I am trying to fetch more than 500 rows of historical data from Binance website but I want more than 500 rows, how do i loop through it and fetch more?

The code i tried:

```
candles= client.get_klines(symbol='ADABTC',interval=Client.KLINE_INTERVAL_1MINUTE)
    candles_data_frame=df(candles)
```

This code fetches 500 rows but i would expect more than 10000 rows of historical data. Please let me know how should i get it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Add the startTime parameter to /api/v1/klines call. Decrease it with each iteration by chosen interval and concat the results into one common array.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-official-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md#klinecandlestick-data the API documentation specifie the limit max at 1000. So in your case you can't get more than 1000 rows

```
candles = client.get_klines(
    symbol='ADABTC',
    interval=Client.KLINE_INTERVAL_1MINUTE,
    limit=1000)
candles_data_frame = df(candles)
```

Comment: It gives only 1000 -> when you get candles_data_frame.shape
(1000, 12)

Comment: Do you have 10000 rows data into candles ? What is df() ?

Comment: Nope i am just calling candles into df and assigning it to candles_data_frame. Overall i get only 1000 rows. If i provide 10000 limit it get 1000 rows and if i dont specify limit, i get 500 rows

Comment: `candles` should contain the number of row define by limit. But you are calling shape with 1000 and 12 as parameters. How do you except more thant 1000 rows ?https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.shape.html

Comment: If i print candles_data_frame i can see in my df i get only 1000 rows :/ 1000 rows × 12 columns

Comment: I guess it's normal if you are using 1000 and 12 as parameter. Did you tried `candles_data_frame.shape (10000, 12)`

Comment: I honestly don't get it, i havent specified parameters. But still get the same 1000 rows.

Comment: @KSp I found the reason. Check my comment edit. There is a limit max set at 1000 :(

Comment: But i dont want the limit to be 1000 but my question is how do i fetch more than that?

Comment: In this case, make multiple requests and concat you result as suggest by Oleksandr Hinko