# get_historical_klines() missing 1 required positional argument: 'start_str'

Tags: python, binance, binance-api-client

I'm trying to get historical data; however upon executing the code:

```
def get_data():
    historical_data = client.get_historical_klines(symbol=config.SYMBOL, interval=Client.KLINE_INTERVAL_1MINUTE, limit=100, klines_type=HistoricalKlinesType.SPOT)
    print(historical_data)
```

I get the error:

```
historical_data = client.get_historical_klines(symbol=config.SYMBOL, interval=Client.KLINE_INTERVAL_1MINUTE, limit=100, klines_type=HistoricalKlinesType.SPOT)
TypeError: get_historical_klines() missing 1 required positional argument: 'start_str'
```

What seems to be wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to provide how much historical data you need. This is made with a 'start_str'. For example :

```
'1 day ago UTC'
'1 hour ago UTC'
```

So you shoud use the function like that:

```
klines = client.get_historical_klines(SYMBOL, Client.KLINE_INTERVAL_15MINUTE , "1 day ago UTC")
```

Comment: I don't need that though. I just need limit 100. I have seen it works for people but not me...

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56349505/fetching-more-data-from-binance-using-python-loop

Comment: I mean... The error tells you that you NEED the start_str. You do what you want, but required positional argument are REQUIRED. Also you should refer to the official docs : [DOCS](https://python-binance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/market_data.ht)

Comment: Also the article that you joined in you previous comment is not for the same function. In your question you use the get_historical_klines() but in the article they use get_klines()